# RestKit crashes when creating mapping for core data entity

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

Im setup restKit with the following configuration method

```
private func createCoreDataStack(){
    var managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil);
    var managedObjectStore = RKManagedObjectStore(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

    var error: NSError?;
    var success = RKEnsureDirectoryExistsAtPath(RKApplicationDataDirectory(), &error);
    if (success == false) {
       // RKLogError("Failed to create Application Data Directory at path '%@': %@", RKApplicationDataDirectory(), error);
    }

    var path:String! = RKApplicationDataDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("DB.sqlite")
    var options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: NSNumber(bool: true), NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: NSNumber(bool: true)]
    var persistentStore = managedObjectStore.addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath(path, fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: nil, withConfiguration: nil, options: options, error: &error)
    if (persistentStore == nil) {
       // RKLogError("Failed adding persistent store at path '%@': %@", path, error);
    }
    managedObjectStore.createManagedObjectContexts()
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache(managedObjectContext: managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext)
    var client = AFHTTPClient(baseURL: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/api"))
    client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = true;
    objectManager = RKObjectManager(HTTPClient: client)

    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore
    managedObjectStore.createPersistentStoreCoordinator()
    RKObjectManager.setSharedManager(objectManager)

    addMapping()
}
```

Also created a gaping for my main entity using the addMapping() method,
something like so:

```
private func addMapping(){
    var mapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "EntityName", inManagedObjectStore: objectManager.managedObjectStore)
    mapping.identificationAttributes = ["id"]
mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["id":"id","uid":"uid","name":"name" ...])
//more code goes here
```

When running the code it crashes on the last line i provided in the addMapping() method (addAttributeMappingFromDictionary) with the exception:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'

Heres a part of the stack trace:

2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105013af8 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 968
    3   FoodBooking                         0x00000001020c2279 __50-[RKPropertyInspector propertyInspectionForClass:]_block_invoke69 + 82
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106cf4614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106cda002 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365
    6   AppName                         0x00000001020c20b5 -[RKPropertyInspector propertyInspectionForClass:] + 886
    7   AppName                         0x00000001020c23d5 -[RKPropertyInspector classForPropertyNamed:ofClass:isPrimitive:] + 62
    8   AppName                         0x0000000102081e5b -[RKEntityMapping classForKeyPath:] + 309

I have no idea what is happening and am open for all and any kind of suggestions

Comment: Are you getting errors before this, is the entity name correct, is this as soon as you create the mapping or when you add the mapping dictionary?

Comment: @Wain It crashes exactly on the last line i provided...mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["id":"id",...